# NPE is being thrown on a static class reference, why and how?

Tags: java, static

I created an Initialize class to avoid a multitude of unneeded objects. To use this object I created an instance of it like so:

```
    public static Initialize INIT = new Initialize();
```

Whenever I use "Initialize.INIT" I get a NullPointer at "Initialize".

What can I do to solve my original error, StackOverflow and avoid NPEs?

Comment: What is the code of the constructor? Note: `public static` variables should _at the very least_ be `final` as well

Comment: Please show us the complete exception with traceback.

Comment: What @PM77-1, and also, show use code samples where you access `Initialize.INIT`. Try and make it final and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the NPE is that **at the time you try to use it** the value of `INIT` is `null`.

How can that be?  After all you initialized it to a new object, and the `new` operator never returns `null`.

Well the most likely explanation is that *something* is assigning `null` to `INIT`.  You should be able to avoid this by declaring the field as `final`.

(It is also possible the you have some code that looks at the value of `INIT` before it has been initialized.  This will only happen if you are executing the static initialization code for some other class, and there is a dependency cycle between the statics of this class and the other one.)